# Working with ADF Faces Calendar Component

Tags: calendar, oracle-adf

I'm working with ADF Faces Calendar Component [Working with ADF Faces Calendar Component](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/calendar-091799.html)

and I'm using JDeveloper and ADF 11g (11.1.1.0.0)
My problem is when i try to expand the Data Controls accordion and drag the collection that represents the view object (FodCalEventVO) and drop it as a Calendar like [ADF Calendar](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/digitalasset/118393.png) i can't find Calendar [like that](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?w0p0v0ahy9fi063).

can you help me how to find it?

Comment: I downloaded the example files and unzipped and tried it and it works for me. I have a single Calendar option in the popup menu. Also, WHY  are you on a release of JDev that is 6 releases back from current production???

Comment: I dont think JDev version matters here, but i agree with Joe that it's better to use a later JDev version like 11.1.1.7 or 11.1.2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ADF Calendar requires a very specific set of objects within your view object before the create calendar menu will appear. See below.

Its most likely because you need to add three bind variables to your view object:

- 2 Date Bind Variables (For storing start date and end date). Make sure Updatable flag is set to true. I also have Required set to ture. Being its 11.1.1.0, it might require 2 timestamp bind variables and not date. But later JDev versions require, 2 date bind variables.
- 1 String Variable (For storing timezone). Make sure updatable flag is set to true.

For your view object's fields, make sure you have attributes for the following:

- 2 Date Attributes (For Start Date and End Date)
- Primary Key Attribute
- String attribute to represent Calendar Activity Provider Id (otherwise owner of calendar activities)
- String attribute to represent Calendar Activity Title.

Lastly, if you had to add any of the above to your view object, make sure you refresh your data controls panel before you create the calendar component from it - its sort of quirky that way :)

Thanks,

Gavin

Comment: Did you try following the steps? The Calendar requires all of the components i listed above, before the Calendar component will show in the create component menu. Mind you, it will only show when you launch the create component menu by dragging over the data-control/View-Object-Instance that will be displaying the calendar data